# make input field visible inside hidden div

Tags: html, input, attributes

Hello I'm trying to make an input field visible which is inside `<div style="display:none">` like this.

```
<div style="display:none">
   <input type="text" value="xyz" [add some attribute to force this input field to be visible or something]>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible with CSS to make child elements visible if a parent element has `display: none`. If the [`:has()`](https://caniuse.com/css-has) selector, which behaves as a parent selector, is supported by browsers you'll have that ability.

Today the only way I can think to do what you are asking would require JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible but you can hide all other elements besides the input with this CSS make sure parent is not hide.

```css
.input-contain-div *:not(.not-hide) {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="input-contain-div">
<input class="not-hide" value="xyz" />
<span>I am hidden</span>
</div>
```

```
.input-contain-div *:not(:input.not-hide) {display:none;}
```